# Best GUI for creating and editing Windows Services

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, windows-services

I want to create windows services with a GUI, but the built-in windows services manager doesn't do this. What is a good windows software that does this well?

What I want to do is open the program, and be able to create a new service that opens an executable file on startup.

P.S. I have tried searching Google but those are all console answers.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? You want to create a new Windows service? More info needed or this will be closed like your previous, similar question.

Comment: @DaveM Edited the question, is that better?

Comment: Next time please edit your existing question and then have it reopened instead of posting a new one. Thanks!

Comment: @slhck I didn't know you could reopen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions is a bit awkward... but I can think of two different answers that may help - if it doesn't, please rephrase your question.

If you mean program your own service from scratch using a real gui, the only thing that springs to mind is [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads).

If you mean just putting an executable as a service, I personally use SrvAny.exe following [Microsoft's guide here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890)... This is because standard exe files run different to services (different entry point(s)), what SrvAny.exe does is it calls a regular exe file but has a wrapper that acts as a service.

The guide above will also show the steps needed for actually making a service from srvany.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, It's not really a graphical user interface